# I get an error while reading multiple multiline JSON files in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory, databricks

I get an  Py4JJavaError message when I'm reading multiple multiline JSON files from a folder. It seems like Spark is struggling while infering a schema from these files.

I tried to reduce the number of files to read since it has to infer from thousands of JSON files but it doesn't seem to work.

```py
def get_user_details_schema(url):
  df = sqlContext.read.json(url, multiLine=True)

  return df.schema
```

This is the message I get :

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2296498238051133> in <module>()
     19 
     20 
---> 21 main()

<command-2296498238051133> in main()
     15 
     16 
---> 17   process_users(config.user_input_url, config.user_output_url)
     18 
     19 

<command-2296498238051133> in process_users(input_url, output_url)
      1 def process_users(input_url, output_url):
----> 2   user_df = get_cleansed_users(input_url)
      3 
      4   if not user_df or user_df.rdd.isEmpty():
      5     print("User input dataset does not exists or is empty. Nothing to do.")

<command-2296498238051132> in get_cleansed_users(input_url)
     16 
     17 def get_cleansed_users(input_url):
---> 18   df = read_if_exists(input_url, get_user_details_schema(input_url))
     19 
     20   formater_date = udf(format_date)

<command-2296498238051132> in get_user_details_schema(url)
      1 def get_user_details_schema(url):
----> 2   df = sqlContext.read.json(url, multiLine=True)
      3 
      4   return df.schema
      5 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in json(self, path, schema, primitivesAsString, prefersDecimal, allowComments, allowUnquotedFieldNames, allowSingleQuotes, allowNumericLeadingZero, allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, dateFormat, timestampFormat, multiLine, allowUnquotedControlChars, lineSep, samplingRatio, dropFieldIfAllNull, encoding)
    272             path = [path]
    273         if type(path) == list:
--> 274             return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    275         elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    276             def func(iterator):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o389.json.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.10.25.4, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2355)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2343)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2574)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2510)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2243)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$.infer(JsonInferSchema.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$$anonfun$infer$1.apply(JsonDataSource.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$$anonfun$infer$1.apply(JsonDataSource.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.infer(JsonDataSource.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonDataSource.inferSchema(JsonDataSource.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.inferSchema(JsonFileFormat.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:195)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:467)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your cluster is running Databricks Runtime 4.0 and above, you can read JSON files in single-line or multi-line mode. In single-line mode, a file can be split into many parts and read in parallel.

**Read JSON files in single-line:**

```
val testJsonData = sqlContext.read.json("/tmp/test.json")
display(testJsonData)
```

[image]

**Read JSON files in multi-line:**

```
val testJsonData = sqlContext.read.option("multiline","true").json("/tmp/test.json")
display(testJsonData)
```

[image]

Reference: [Azure Databricks - JSON Files](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-json.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This example seems to indicate data is being dropped.  Is that correct?